# How to get full url from django request

Tags: python, django

Is there a better way to get the full url in django than doing the following:

```
url = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    + request.META['PATH_INFO']
    + request.META['QUERY_STRING']
```

Is there something like `request.META['URL']` ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can get full URL using `request.build_absolute_uri` method:

```
FULL_URL_WITH_QUERY_STRING: request.build_absolute_uri()
FULL_URL: request.build_absolute_uri('?')
ABSOLUTE_ROOT: request.build_absolute_uri('/')[:-1].strip("/")
ABSOLUTE_ROOT_URL: request.build_absolute_uri('/').strip("/")
```

Should this will help full to you.

The best way to use ABSOLUTE URLS in Django, you can create a context_processors or middleware and  find your `ABSOLUTE_URL` and return that so that you can use any where in Django.

Like this example:

```
def absolute(request):
    urls = {
        'ABSOLUTE_ROOT': request.build_absolute_uri('/')[:-1].strip("/"),
        'ABSOLUTE_ROOT_URL': request.build_absolute_uri('/').strip("/"),
    }

    return urls
```

And Then you should use `{{ABSOLUTE_ROOT}}` in any where into you django template.

Answer (score 34):

You can use:

```
request.build_absolute_uri()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri

Comment: request.build_absolute_uri('url') is giving `http://localhost:8000/pary/url` but not the parameter for the full url `http://localhost:8000/pary/?url=https://jobs.chegg.com/#categoryName#-jobs&uid=OIKAHY&env_id=4
` Can you please tell where am I doing wrong?

Comment: `request.build_absolute_uri` doesn't take a url.  It builds the url from the request information.

Answer (score -2):

you can use

**in template**

```html
{{ request.META.PATH_INFO }}
```

**in views**

```py
end_point = request.META.get('PATH_INFO', None)    # not recommend
```

please use **David542**'s answer

```py
request.build_absolute_uri()
```

Comment: The OP is aware of this attribute as stated in the question.  This doesn't give the full URI, as stated in the question.