# How to get the full URL of a static asset in a Django template?

Tags: django-templates

[This guide on slack URL unfurling](https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-unfurling-but-were-afraid-to-ask-or-how-to-make-your-e64b4bb9254) says to use the full URL to an image.

In Django a static asset is gotten with:

```
{% static '/path/to/asset.jpg' %}
```

which returns a partial path.

[This slack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26989132) says to get the full URL of something, use `request.build_absolute_uri`.  For example:

```
{% request.build_absolute_uri 'some_thing' %}
```

However, I don't know how to combine the `static` tag (which can add cache-busting hex digits) and the `request.build_absolute_uri` function.

How do I get the full URL to a static asset in a Django template?

Answer (score 0):

I made an answer, though I'm happy if someone finds a better one.

```
{{request.scheme}}://{{ request.get_host }}{% static '/path/to/asset.jpg' %}
```

I also made a tag for the first part:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def request_scheme_and_host(context):
    request = context['request']
    return request.scheme + '://' + request.get_host()
```

Then it's

```
{% load tags %}

{% request_scheme_and_host %}{% static '/path/to/asset.jpg' %}
```

You can read more on [Creating Django template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags)